# How to keep color profiles when converting images

Tags: image-resizing, imageresizer

When I resize images using imageresizing.net(FreeImageDecode) library in the output image the color profile sRGB is ignored.
How to keep the color profile sRGB when converting?
I have set the ignoreicc=false

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/59/93596133.png/

Answer (score 0):

The version of FreeImage used in the FreeImageDecoder plugin is currently compiled without metadata/icc support for performance reasons (250% performance boost).

Everything is performed in sRGB anyway; so there shouldn't be any practical problem unless your source files aren't sRGB.

We're hoping the FreeImage team will allow this to be set with a flag instead of requiring recompilation. At the moment there's no way for us to support both good performance and ICC flexibility when using the FreeImage plugins.